# The best practice solution of differenses search of two STL vectors

Tags: c++, stl

I have already two STL vectors. For instance:

```
vector<int> MyList;
MyList.push_back(10);
MyList.push_back(20);
MyList.push_back(30);
MyList.push_back(40);
MyList.push_back(50);

vector<int> MyListSub;  
MyListSub.push_back(20);
MyListSub.push_back(30);
MyListSub.push_back(40);
```

And I want to get the number of elements which is in the MyListSub and isn't in MyList.
For this instance, result is "2"

Comment: Your example is backwards. All elements in `MyListSub` are also in `MyList`. I assume you meant it the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`std::set_difference`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/) for this:

```
std::vector<int> diff;
std::set_difference(MyList.begin(), MyList.end(),
                    MyListSub.begin(), MyListSub.end(),
                    std::back_inserter(diff));
```

As @Jan points out, the vectors have to be sorted. If they are not, use `std::sort` to sort them:

```
std::sort(MyList.begin(), MyList.end());
```

Alternatively you can consider storing your elements in an `std::set` in the first place, thus they will already be sorted.

Comment: Important note: The vectors have to be sorted!